# Determine whether given points are be the limit points of the given set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $P=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 0 \le x^2 \lt 1, 2 \lt y \le 4\}$ and
$S = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 1 \le x \le 3, y = 2 \}$.

1. Are $(0,3)$ and $(0,4)$ be the limit points of $P$? Is $P$ be open set?
2. Are all points of $S \cup P$ be the limit points of $S \cup P$?

Please help for the second questions by analytics.
For example, let $(a,b) \in S \cup P$. To show that $(a,b)$ is a limit point of $S \cup P$. That is, to show that for all $r \gt 0, B((0,3),r) \cap (S \cup P) \setminus \{(a,b) \}$. How to approach this?

Here's my attempt for 1.

For $(0,3)$. Let $r \gt 0$. Want to show that $B((0,3),r) \cap P \setminus \{(0,3) \} \in P$.
Choose $(x,y) = (0,3 + \frac{r}{2})$ if $r \lt 1$, and $(x,y) = (0,\frac{7}{2})$ if $r \ge 1$.
Then, for $r \lt 1$:
$||(x,y) - (0,3)|| = \frac{r}{2} \lt r$. Hence, $(x,y) \in B((0,3),r)$. Clearly, $-1<0=x<1$ and $2<3<3+\frac{r}{2} < 4$. Hence, $(x,y) \in P$. Thus, $(x,y) \ne (0,3)$. Therefore,
$(0,3) \in B((0,3),r) \cap P \setminus \{(0,3)\}$.

Next, analogue for $r \gt 1$. Hence, $(0,3)$ is a limit point of $P$. And the analogue method for $(0,4)$. Am I true?

How about the second questions? Ca I approach like this:
showing all points in $S$ are the limit points of $S$ and also for $P$.
? Then, if yes, all limit points of $S$ is the limit points of $S \cup P$, also for $P$ ?

Comment: You can show separately that any point in $S$ is a limit point of $P\cup S$, and any point in $P$ is a limit point of $P\cup S$. It's unnecessary to show all point in $S$ is a limit point of $S$ and them argue that any limit point in $S$ is also a limit point of $P\cup S$.

Comment: how to show any points of $S$ is limit point of $S \cup P$?

Comment: How if I show all points of $S$ is a limit point of $S$ then since $S \subseteq S \cup S$, then $S \cup P$ contains all point of $S$. similarly for $P$?